# Prove that this matrix is total unimodular

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, integer-programming

Is there an easy way to prove that this matrix is **total unimodular** ?
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
  1 & F_1 & 0\\
  1 & 0 & F^T_1 \\
  0 & F_2
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$1$ is the identity matrix, and $F_1, F_2$ are network matrices (so per row they have one +1 and one -1 entry or only one +1 entry) [$F^T_1$ is the transposed matrix, $F_2$ is as big as $[0 \; F^T_1]$ ].

I already proved that the matrix without the row $[1 \; 0 \; F^T_1]$ is total unimodular.

Comment: Your block matrix is not well defined. Since you have two identity matrices on the first column, they must be of the same size. It follows that $F_1$ is a square matrix (isn't it?). But then $F_2$ has more columns than $F_1$ and it is not possible they are in the same column. Did you mean that $F_2$ spans the second and the third columns instead?

Answer (score 2):

The matrix is not totally unimodular, in general. A simple counterexample is if $F_1=[1\,-1]$. Then your matrix contains as a submatrix $[1\, F_1^T]$. This is
$$\left[\begin{array}{rr}
1 & 1\\
1 & -1
\end{array}\right]$$
which has determinant 2.

Comment: Welcome to the **Mathematics Stack Exchange** (MSE)! Congratulations for your first answer!